# Union of two selects in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'd like to do something like

```
{
    SELECT ?page, "A" AS ?type WHERE 
    {
         ?s rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en;
            foaf:page ?page
    }
}
UNION
{
    SELECT ?page, "B" AS ?type WHERE 
    {
         ?s rdfs:label "Apple"@en;
            foaf:page ?page
    }
}
```

But this gives a syntax error. How can I union two select queries in SPARQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @user205512's answer, here's one that works on Virtuoso:

```
SELECT * {
    ?s foaf:page ?page .
    {
        SELECT ?page ("A" AS ?type) {
            ?s rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en;
               foaf:page ?page
        }
    } UNION {
        SELECT ?page ("B" AS ?type) {
            ?s rdfs:label "Apple"@en;
               foaf:page ?page
        }
    }
}
```

The trick was just do add an additional `?s foaf:page ?page` triple outside of the `UNION`. This is obviously redundant, but it seems to avoid the Virtuoso bug, which is apparently caused when you have a “naked” `UNION` with subqueries.

Answer (score 16):

You can union them like this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT * WHERE
{ 
{
    SELECT ?page ("A" AS ?type) WHERE 
    {
         ?s rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en;
            foaf:page ?page
    }
}
UNION
{
    SELECT ?page ("B" AS ?type) WHERE 
    {
         ?s rdfs:label "Apple"@en;
            foaf:page ?page
    }
}
}
```

(check with the [SPARQL validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html))

However I don't think you need sub queries at all for this case. For example:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?page ?type WHERE
{
    ?s foaf:page ?page .
    { ?s rdfs:label "Microsoft"@en . BIND ("A" as ?type) }
    UNION
    { ?s rdfs:label "Apple"@en . BIND ("B" as ?type) }
}
```

Comment: That gives me this error: "SPARQL compiler: Internal error: ssg_print_equiv_retval_expn(): select selid is out of scope." 

I'm trying to get this working on http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: Oh, with virtuoso (which powers that endpoint) I really don't know. Their SPARQL support is idiosyncratic.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems that your first query doesn't work in dbpedia due to a virtuoso bug and BIND doesn't appear to be implemented in virtuoso, they like to make it hard for us...!